# Como usar script random

Tags: javascript, random

Eu possuo 3 scripts do Google adsense com 300 x 250 - 160 x 600 - 728 x 90

Como faço para cada vez que a pagina seja carregada 1 desses script seja mostrado?

Gostaria que cada Reload da pagina seja mostrado 1 script.

Exemplo:

Eu possuo esse que é usado para iframe, mas no caso do adsense eu preciso que seja usado o script completo.

```
    <script language="JavaScript">
    var quotes=new Array()
     quotes[0]='<iframe frameborder="0" height="250" name="videoplayer" 
    scrolling="no" src="http://" style="border: 0px #FFFFFF none;" width="300">
   </iframe>'
      quotes[1]='<iframe frameborder="0" height="250" name="videoplayer" 
      scrolling="no" src="http://" 
      style="border: 0px #FFFFFF none;" width="300"></iframe>'
      quotes[2]='<iframe frameborder="0" height="250" name="videoplayer" 
      scrolling="no" src="http://" style="border: 0px #FFFFFF none;" width="300"></iframe>'
      var whichquote=Math.floor(Math.random()*(quotes.length))
      document.write(quotes[whichquote])
      </script>
```

Blocos que quero usar no mo Randon

```
       <script async 
       src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
        </script>
         <!-- lateral -->
         <ins class="adsbygoogle"
     style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px"
     data-ad-client="ca-pub-2068602933738629"
      data-ad-slot="8173528505"></ins>
            <script>
          (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
         </script>

         <script async 
       src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
        </script>  <ins
         class="adsbygoogle"
          style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px"
            data-ad-client="ca-pub-2068602933738629"
             data-ad-slot="2353050305"></ins> <script>(adsbygoogle = 
         window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script>

              <script async 

          src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js">
               </script>
           <!-- celular -->
           <ins class="adsbygoogle"
           style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px"
           data-ad-client="ca-pub-2068602933738629"
          data-ad-slot="6337832563"></ins>
            <script>
           (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
            </script>
```

Comment: E queres evitar repetir um deles antes "dar a volta" ou pode ser repetido randomicamente?

Comment: Pode ser repetido, mas que os outros script tambem sejam mostrados

Comment: Coloquei uma resposta. Se tiveres código ou urls desses scripts que não saibas como integrar coloca na pergunta.

Comment: Juntei um exemplo na resposta.

Comment: Adicionei os script que quero usar , esse exemplo de iframe que mostrei eu não posso usar pq o google não deixa, preciso usar o codigo do proprio google na pagina, não posso usar iframe

Comment: Esse futebol é de outro mundo huehuehue

Answer (score 2):

O `Math.random()` dá-te um numero decimal entre `0` e `1`.

Para ter um numero entre 0 e 2 podes fazer `Math.random() * 2`, ou seja no máximo é 2 no mínimo é 0.

Para teres somente inteiros (para usar como indice de array por exemplo) podes usar `Math.round()`.

```
function gerarNumero(){
    return Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
}
```

Se quiseres garantir que um numero só é sorteado uma vez a cada iteração dos outros números não dá para fazer isso só no browser, tens de ter lógica no servidor.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
(function() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.src = "https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});

  function gerarNumero(max) {
    return Math.round(Math.random() * max);
  }
  var quotes = [
    '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:160px;height:600px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-2068602933738629" data-ad-slot="2353050305"></ins>',
    '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:300px;height:250px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-2068602933738629" data-ad-slot="8173528505"></ins>',
    '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display:inline-block;width:320px;height:100px" data-ad-client="ca-pub-2068602933738629" data-ad-slot="6337832563"></ins>'
  ];
  var index = gerarNumero(quotes.length - 1);
  var adDiv = document.createElement('div');
  adDiv.innerHTML = quotes[index]
  document.body.appendChild(adDiv.children[0]);
})();
```

Comment: Esse exemplo funciona bem com iframe, mas preciso usar o script completo ao inves do iframe

Comment: @Endou juntei o exemplo com a nova versão, era um ajuste pequeno.

Comment: Não é possivel usar o script inteiro? não posso mexer no codigo preciso usar ele inteiro e sem modificações